# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout.setError(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-textinputedittext

i am using AwesomeValidation library for validation, the app crashes & gives a null object reference error ,i am not able to find what is reffering to null help .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.admin.auctioner.SignupActivity"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="25dp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="82dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/logodesc"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView4"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="34dp"
    android:fontFamily="monospace"
    android:text="@string/app_name"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView5"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="22dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:text="@string/signuptxt"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textInputLayout3"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4" />

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/textInputLayout3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    app:errorEnabled="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textInputLayout4"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView5">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/s_email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/textInputLayout4"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="74dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="9dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    app:errorEnabled="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textInputLayout5"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout3"
    app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/s_pass1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/password"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/textInputLayout5"
    android:layout_width="395dp"
    android:layout_height="79dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="13dp"
    app:errorEnabled="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button4"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button4"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/button4"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout4"
    app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/s_pass2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/cpassword"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="190dp"
    android:layout_height="44dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:onClick="signup"
    android:text="@string/signup"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView6"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout5" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="65dp"
    android:onClick="login_link"
    android:text="@string/llink"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button4"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/button4"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button4" />
```

here is the activity code :

public class SignupActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
TextInputEditText email,pass1,pass2;
FirebaseAuth mAuth;
AwesomeValidation mAwesomeValidation;
ProgressDialog progressDialog;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Registering user");
    email = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.s_email);
    pass1 = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.s_pass1);
    pass2 = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.s_pass2);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    mAwesomeValidation = new AwesomeValidation(TEXT_INPUT_LAYOUT);
    mAwesomeValidation.addValidation(this,R.id.s_email, Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS, R.string.emailerr);
    String regexPassword = "(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[\\d])(?=.*[~`!@#\\$%\\^&\\*\\(\\)\\-_\\+=\\{\\}\\[\\]\\|\\;:\"<>,./\\?]).{8,}";
    mAwesomeValidation.addValidation(this, R.id.s_pass1, regexPassword, R.string.passerr);
    mAwesomeValidation.addValidation(this, R.id.s_pass2, R.id.s_pass1, R.string.passerr);


}

public void signup(View view){
    email.setError("Enter valid email");
    if (mAwesomeValidation.validate()){
        String mail = email.getText().toString().trim();
        String pass = pass1.getText().toString().trim();
        progressDialog.show();

        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(mail,pass).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Registered successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LoginActivity.class));
                }
                else {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Registration Error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

        progressDialog.dismiss();

    }
}
```

i get this error

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.example.admin.auctioner, PID: 20721
              java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
               Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637) 
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429) 
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776) 
               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout.setError(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                  at com.basgeekball.awesomevalidation.validators.TextInputLayoutValidator.halt(SourceFile:30)
                  at com.basgeekball.awesomevalidation.validators.TextInputLayoutValidator.trigger(SourceFile:23)
                  at com.basgeekball.awesomevalidation.AwesomeValidation.validate(SourceFile:139)
                  at com.example.admin.auctioner.SignupActivity.signup(SignupActivity.java:58)
```

i have tried to put in OnStart() method also 
getting the same error ?

Comment: `email` is `null`

Comment: the email textInputEditText field has content in it  ?

Comment: there might be content in the TextField, but your reference to the text field `email` is empty!

Comment: ya i understand the error but can you tell me where is that generated from,

Comment: i have also tried removing 
email.setError("Enter valid email");

Comment: `email = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.s_email);` does not give you a correct reference. check with debugger

Comment: can you tell me the solution to fix the error ?

Comment: Where are you calling `signup`?

Comment: i have added it to onclick() on the signup button

Comment: Can you post your XML layout file as well?

Comment: i have added my xml